# Insert missing dates in flat file of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, with dates missing. Is it possible to update this dataframe with all dates in the first column for February and March. I want the prices for the missing dates to be 0 and the product to be either Pencils or pens to make a complete list. The data frame don't always be in the correct order, so Ffill shouldn't be used.

```
               Price   Product
1/Feb/2020      4400     Pencils
2/Feb/2020      0        Pencils
3/Feb/2020      0        Pencils
27/Feb/2020     0        Pencils
28/Feb/2020     0        Pencils
1/Mar/2020      55000    Pencils
2/Mar/2020       0       Pencils
3/Mar/2020       0       Pencils
30/Mar/2020      0       Pencils
31/Mar/2020      0       Pencils
1/Feb/2020      4400     Pens
2/Feb/2020      4454     Pens
3/Feb/2020      0        Pens
27/Feb/2020     34534    Pens
28/Feb/2020     345345   Pens
1/Mar/2020      550345   Pens
2/Mar/2020       354     Pens
3/Mar/2020       454     Pens
30/Mar/2020      454     Pens
31/Mar/2020     4545     Pens
```

Comment: reindex doesn't work as I can't pivot the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea if always exist first and last values per months is reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), add missing datetimes by [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) and reshape back by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = (df.set_index('Product', append=True)
        .unstack()
        .asfreq('d')
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .sort_index(level=[1,0])
        .reset_index(level=1))
print (df)
            Product   Price
2020-02-01  Pencils  4400.0
2020-02-02  Pencils     0.0
2020-02-03  Pencils     0.0
2020-02-04  Pencils     NaN
2020-02-05  Pencils     NaN
            ...     ...
2020-03-27     Pens     NaN
2020-03-28     Pens     NaN
2020-03-29     Pens     NaN
2020-03-30     Pens   454.0
2020-03-31     Pens  4545.0

[120 rows x 2 columns]
```

General solution with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and `date_range`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

#convert minimal/ maximal datetimes for first and last day of month
s = df.index.min().to_period('m').to_timestamp()
e = df.index.max().to_period('m').to_timestamp(how='e')

df = (df.set_index('Product', append=True)
        .unstack()
        .reindex(pd.date_range(s, e))
        .stack(dropna=False)
        .sort_index(level=[1,0])
        .reset_index(level=1))
```